# Upgraded to Windows 10, problems with touchpad

Tags: touchpad, windows-10-upgrade

Lenovo, Yoga Pro 3
I have upgraded to Windows 10, and unfortunately, the touchpad is not working at all. When i connect the mouse it works, but the touchpad that is in the computer is not.
I do not know what to do.
Is there any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Thank you,
Yuliya

Comment: Check for driver update on Lenovo's website!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.  It works and then it stops.  The 2 finger scroll works intermittently.  I do not see any new drivers.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.